# AngularJS: Routing doesn't work regardless of whitelist

Tags: angularjs

I can't properly whitelist urls.

I'm getting "Error: [$sce:insecurl]".

The paths exist, and when I place the templates in the same folder it all works.

What is the problem?

```
var platform = angular.module('platform', ['ngRoute', 'testControllers', 'testServices']);

platform.config(['$sceDelegateProvider', '$routeProvider',
  function($sceDelegateProvider, $routeProvider) {
    //$sceDelegateProvider.resourceUrlWhitelist(['self', '../templates/**']);
    $sceDelegateProvider.resourceUrlWhitelist(['self', 'C:/Users/Royi/Desktop/Platform/templates/**']);

    $routeProvider.
      when('/', {
        templateUrl: 'C:/Users/Royi/Desktop/Platform/templates/text.html',
        controller: 'testController'
      }).
      when('/:pageId', {
        templateUrl: 'C:/Users/Royi/Desktop/Platform/templates/text.html',
        controller: 'testController'
      }).
      otherwise({
        redirectTo: '/'
    });
  }]);
```

Answer (score 0):

C:/ is not usually an URL accessible over HTTP. The page may pick up items in the local directory, but for using C:/ you should usually use file:///C:/ (note the third slash).

Also, as paths on your own drive can't be "trusted" by something like Chrome, you'll be getting issues. See the documentation for insecurl [enter link description here](https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$sce/insecurl)

Comment: file:/// doesn't help.
I tried to disable sce altogether so I can develop locally, but it didn't work either.

Comment: That's how I tried to disable it, in case it's not obvious:
$sceProvider.enabled(false);